# Let $X,Y$ be independent RV's and suppose $F_X$ is continuous. Show $P(X=Y)=0$ and tell if $P(X=Y)=1$ is possible if $F_X$ is not continuous.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $X,Y$ be independent RV's and suppose $F_X$ is continuous. Show $P(X=Y)=0$ and tell if $P(X=Y)=1$ is possible if $F_X$ is not continuous.

My idea is:

$P(X=Y) = F_X(Y=y) - \lim_{z \rightarrow y_{-}}F_X(Y=z)$.

But since $F_X$ is continuous we have $\lim_{z \rightarrow y_{-}}F_X(Y=z) = F(Y = y)$ and so $P(X=Y) = 0$.

However, I don't know how to show the second part and provide an example.

Could I define $X,Y = 1$ to be discrete ? Then $\lim_{z \rightarrow 1_{-}}F_X(Y=z) = 0$ ?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are both constant then  it can easily be checked that $P\left(X\in A,Y\in B\right)=P\left(X\in A\right)P\left(Y\in B\right)$
wich means exactly that they are independent. So $X=Y=1$ works here.

Comment: Since $F_X$ is continuous you have $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$. Thus $P(X=Y)=P((X,Y)\in D)={\rm E}[g(Y)]$, where $D$ is the diagonal in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $g(y)=P((X,y)\in D\mid Y=y)=P(X=y)=0$ for all $y$. Hence $P(X=Y)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

In general $P\left(X=Y\right)=\int\int f\left(x,y\right)dF_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)$
where $f\left(x,y\right)=1$ if $x=y$ and $f\left(x,y\right)=0$
otherwise.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then that results in $$P\left(X=Y\right)=\int\int f\left(x,y\right)dF_{X}\left(x\right)dF_{Y}\left(y\right)=\int P(X=y)dF_{Y}\left(y\right)$$

If moreover $F_{X}$ is continuous then $P(X=y)=0$ for each $y$, and consequently $P\left(X=Y\right)=0$.

Note that it is enough if only one of $X,Y$ is continuously distributed. This because we have also: $$P\left(X=Y\right)=\int P(Y=x)dF_{X}\left(x\right)$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are both constant then it can easily be checked that: $$P(X\in A,Y\in B)=P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$$ wich means exactly that they are independent. So $X=Y=1$ works here.

Comment: Thanks @drhab. Is my calculations in proving the first part correctly or does it violate something ?

Comment: What is the exact meaning of $F_{X}\left(Y=y\right)$? Here $F_{X}$
is just a function on $\mathbb{R}$, but is $Y=y$ an element of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, $Y=y$ is an element of $\mathbb R$ corresponding to a value of $Y$.

Comment: Wich element? $y$? Then what is the difference with $F_X(y)$? If there is any.

Comment: In fact you are stating that $P\left(X=y\right)=F_{X}\left(y\right)-\lim_{z\uparrow y}F_{X}\left(z\right)=0$
for every fixed $y$ but not that $P\left(X=Y\right)=0$. Also note that the independence is not used in your proof.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind explaining: If moreover $F_{X}$ is continuous then $\int f\left(x,y\right)dF_{X}\left(x\right)=0$
for each $y$ and consequently $P\left(X=Y\right)=0$. If $F_{X}$ is continuous why is the integral zero ?

Comment: Note that here $\int f\left(x,y\right)dF_{X}\left(x\right)=P\left\{ X=y\right\} $
and you proved that $P\left\{ X=y\right\} =0$ for each fixed $y$
didn't you? That was okay to do and is used here, but it was not enough.
My answer completes your start with a finish.

Comment: Should this also be proved in the discrete case ? In the discrete case $F_X$ cannot be continuous can it ? Also I see your point, your integral is only evaluated at one point for each $y$ and since $\int 0 \ dx = 0$ and $\int f(x,y) dF_X(x)$ is different from $0$ at only one point it must have integral $0$ as well.

Comment: For the discrete case you can just come up with: 'yes, $P(X=Y)=1$ together with independence is possible. $X=Y=1$ is a good example of that'. More isn't asked of you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @drhab. Your help and input has been very inspiring and gave me some new ideas regarding this subject of mathematics.

Comment: You are very welcome.